# How to increase the response timeout for long process API on IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, postman, swagger

I Developed an api using asp.net core and publish it on IIS. It has an action that needs to long time for complete and show response, but when i call that from Swagger or Postman, i get error 503 after about 15 seconds, while the codes are running in the background.

I increase Connection Timeout in Advance settings of site in iis, but it didn't work.
can you help me?

Comment: Can you provide the configuration of the binding and web.config on your IIS? Are you sending requests to your api by ip?

Comment: I prefer that don't use web.config, Is there no other solution?
yes, i sending requests by ip

Comment: Did you set the host name when binding the site in IIS? When you access it via IP, IIS does not know which site it is, and it will give a 503 error. Please try to set Host Name to blank for Site Binding of IIS.